# Layout error when sending a multiline string as message with discord bot

Tags: python, layout, discord.py, multiline, multilinestring

I got a discord bot up and running. My goal is to send a message to the user after a certain command. This works, but somehow my layout is wrong. The first line of my string is correct and after that the rest is send with some leading spaces.

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/')

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    welcome_message = f"""
    Welcome to my bot
    here is a new line which has leading spaces
    this line here has some aswell
    """
    await ctx.send(welcome_message)
```

So basically my message looks like this:

```
Welcome to my bot
    here is a new line which has leading spaces
    this line here has some aswell
```

Even with `welcome_message = welcome_message.lstrip()` before sending doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indentation in this case is part of the string (since it's a multiline string), you could simply remove it:

```py
@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    welcome_message = welcome_message = f"""
Welcome to my bot
here is a new line which has leading spaces
this line here has some aswell
    """
    await ctx.send(welcome_message)
```

If you want to keep the indentation use the [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) method:

```py
import textwrap

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    welcome_message = welcome_message = f"""
    Welcome to my bot
    here is a new line which has leading spaces
    this line here has some aswell
    """
    await ctx.send(textwrap.dedent(welcome_message))
```

Comment: I thought strings weren't exempt from indentation as it would fall out of scope. Is it always like this in python?

Comment: The indentation is still part of the multiline string (since it's still inside the quotes).